# Jquery "select all" checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select all checkboxes on a page once the 'select all' checkbox is clicked and i am using jquery for this as you can see at the below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/priyam/K9P8A/

The code to select and unselect all checkbox is:

```
function selectAll() {
    $('.selectedId').attr('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
}

function isChecked(checkboxId) {
    var id = '#' + checkboxId;
    return $(id).is(":checked");
}
```

After being stuck with it for a day, I am still not sure why I cant get it to work. Please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Your fiddle works after I made 3 fixes](http://jsfiddle.net/5XMW4/) :

- import of jQuery (top left menu)
- addition of the missing `isChecked` function
- use of [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` to check the boxes

Comment: @destroy thanks for help...but even after the fix if you click on selectall thrice it stops working

Comment: this only works for the first time, try checking/un-checking again

Comment: @wizkid Maybe you're trying the initial version, but the last edit (more than 6 minutes ago though) fixed it.

Comment: @dystroy why? was there a specific reason.

Comment: @defau1t That's just I didn't want rep for this. But that's not important.

Comment: @dystroy; thats strange. Do you have allergy with reputations. why don't you transfer some to me..

Comment: When I run this on my localhost, it doesn't work. Why is that? I've downloaded the JQuery library, jquery-1.11.0. Does that have to do with it?

Comment: @defau1t: Why would you make an answer community Wiki when it links the solution to a Fiddle without any code in the answer? This answer deservers a downvote, which I am going to give it now.

Comment: @dan-klasson Why isn't the code in the answer ? Because everything that matters is already in the answer and because repeating the code here wouldn't help. Especially when the most important part of the answer is a misconfiguration of the fiddle which can't be put as code here. Please read a little questions and answers before commenting, you're not helping the community.

Comment: 7 lines of code is hardly bad to repeat. Especially since you made changes to it. You could have copied the code and put comments where you made changes. And you still haven't answered how this is a good community Wiki.

Answer (score 24):

Why don't you do it this way? It is more clear and readable

```
$('#selectall').click(function () {
    $('.selectedId').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('.selectedId').change(function () {
    var check = ($('.selectedId').filter(":checked").length == $('.selectedId').length);
    $('#selectall').prop("checked", check);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K9P8A/13/)

Comment: Good solution, using it (!). Little simplification: `var check = ( $('.selectedId').length == $('.selectedId:checked').length );`

Comment: thanks. lately I have been using `:checked` pseudo selector as well

Comment: Thanks. your code is very simple and is better because when click on `Select All` and then uncheck one of checkboxes, then `selectall checkbox` change to uncheck. LIKE!

Comment: Props for the change function. It makes the interaction more polished.

Answer (score 7):

It is because the method `selectAll` is not avaible in the global scope.

In the second dropdown in the left panel `Frameworks and Extensions`, select `no -wrap head/body` it will work fine.

The reason being by default `onload` is selected and when onload is selected all the entered script is wrapped inside a anonymous function as given below. It will make the `selectAll` function a local method inside the anonymous function, thus your onclick event handler which uses global scope will not get access to the method causing an `Uncaught ReferenceError: selectAll is not defined` error.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //Entered script
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dsjwn/)

**Update**
But you can simplify it as

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectall').click(function(i, v){
        $('.selectedId').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    var checkCount = $('.selectedId').length;
    $('.selectedId').click(function(i, v){
        $('#selectall').prop('checked',$('.selectedId:checked').length  == checkCount)
    });
});
```

and remove all the `onclick` handlers from input elements as shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dsjwn/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Use this...

```
$('#selectall').on('click', function() {
    $('.selectedId').attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

An see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9P8A/14/)

Comment: ops, simple but not "unselect" the selectall-checkbox. See @letiagoalves solution.

Comment: @PeterKrauss yes, i forgot the code to unselect the checkbox #selectall. The code of letiagolves it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectall').click(function () {
        $('.selectedId').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});

more Optimized
```

Comment: same comment as @MG_Bautista

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectall').click(function () {
         var checked = $(this).is(':checked');            
        $('.selectedId').each(function () {
            var checkBox = $(this);               
            if (checked) {
                checkBox.prop('checked', true);                
            }
            else {
                checkBox.prop('checked', false);                
            }
        });

    });
});
```

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ra3uL/

Comment: ops, simple but not "unselect" the selectall-checkbox when another item is "deselected". See @letiagoalves solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assume parent checkbox has a class of mainselect and all child have class of childselect

Then selecting parent will select all checkbox and vice-versa with the code below:

```
$('#mainselect').live('change',function(){
if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
    $('.childselect').attr('checked','checked');
} else {
    $('.childselect').removeAttr('checked');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(function(){

```
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

A small enhancement to @letiagoalves solution, if your checkboxes have specific processing associated with a click event.  Not asked for by the OP, but something I've had to do in the past.  Basically, instead of directly setting the checked property of each dependent checkbox, it compares the checked state of each dependent checkbox to the selectall checkbox, and triggers a click event on those that are in the opposite state.

```
$('#selectall').click(function () {
    var parentState = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.selectedId').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') !== parentState) {
            $(this).trigger("click");
        }
});
});
```

DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/jajntuqb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the handle function to the click event on the select all checkbox:

```
$('#chk-all-items').click(selectAll);
```

And then this function should be enough to select all or unselect all.

```
selectAll = function (event) {
        var self = this;
        $('.template-item-select').each(function () {
            this.checked = self.checked;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

More specific solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkAll').on('click', function ( e ) {
    $('input[name="chck_box[]"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck_box[]" value="1"></td>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck_box[]" value="2"></td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck_box[]" value="3"></td>
      <td>Bill</td>
      <td>White</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```