# HTML checkbox when select all tick doesn't show

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

```
<table class="list" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="first" width="1" style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', this.checked);"></td>
            <td class="left">
                Username
            </td>
            <td class="left">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="left">
                Date Added
            </td>
            <td class="right">
                Action
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="2">
            </td>
            <td class="left">testing</td>
            <td class="left">Enabled</td>
            <td class="left">31/08/2013</td>
            <td class="right"> [ <a href="">Edit</a> ]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="1">
            </td>
            <td class="left">admin</td>
            <td class="left">Enabled</td>
            <td class="left">31/03/2013</td>
            <td class="right">[ <a href="">Edit</a> ]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I got a checkbox when click will select all others checkbox, the first time click the select all, others check box will checked shown tick. But When uncheck the select all and select it again, the others checkbox doesn't shown tick but when view source code checked="checked" does shown

Comment: And also clarify your horrible description.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879608/jquery-select-all-checkbox/15880040#15880040)

Comment: The JS code is there - it is on the element: `onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', this.checked);"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious but the original code is embedded in the markup above.

Note the use of `$(…)`

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', this.checked);">
```

Change:

```
.attr('checked', this.checked);
```

to:

```
.prop('checked', this.checked);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bftGb/)

For more information see [$.prop - Attributed vs Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Specifically:

> ...the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does.