# jQuery Select All Checkbox with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have seen other examples of this but have not successfully gotten this to function correctly.  The examples I have seen also are just using regular checkboxes.  I have used a class to stylize the checkbox with a sprite sheet so having a bit of trouble taking the ideas of these other examples and applying them to my case.

Here is the mark up:

```
<div id="showHideAll"">Show/Hide All<input type="checkbox" id="allCheck" name="pinSet" class="pinToggles" onclick="checkAllLinks()">
    <label for="allCheck" class="css-label"></label></div>
</div>

<div>Opt1<input type="checkbox" id="opt1Check" name="pinSet" class="pinToggles" onclick="checkOpt1Links()">
    <label for="opt1Check" class="css-label"></label>
</div>

<div>Opt2<input type="checkbox" id="opt2Check" name="pinSet" class="pinToggles" onclick="checkOpt2Links()">
     <label for="opt2Check" class="css-label"></label>
</div>

<div>Opt3<input type="checkbox" id="opt3Check" name="pinSet" class="pinToggles" onclick="checkOpt3Links()">
     <label for="dinShopCheck" class="css-label"></label>
</div>
```

The checked property is what changes the sprite using a css class.

```
input[type=checkbox].pinToggles:checked + label.css-label {
background-position: 0 -16px;
}
```

Most of this is for other functionality but thought I would show it just in case.

This is how I set up the individual checkboxes:

```
function checkOpt1Links(){
    $('#opt1 li a').toggleClass("inactive");

 if(opt1.getVisible() == true)
    {       
        opt1.setOptions({visible:false});
    }
    else
    {
        opt1.setOptions({visible:true});
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is the typical select all checkbox functionality, where if you check it the boxes all check, if you uncheck they all uncheck but also if you click a box when select all is checked the select all and the clicked checkbox uncheck and vice versa.  I did look at this example: [Jquery "select all" checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879608/jquery-select-all-checkbox)  but just having difficult time making it work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this closer to what you are thinking: http://jsfiddle.net/rXhan/1/ ?

Comment: Not really.  I want them to be able to uncheck individual ones even though the show/hide all is checked.  Really the best example I can show of what I want is this fiddle from the other question:http://jsfiddle.net/5XMW4/

Answer (score 0):

1) Use **`change`** event handler instead of `click` for `checkbox` and `radio` buttons.

You can make it simple like this

```
$('#showHideAll').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
    if ($('.pinToggles').is(':checked')) {
        $('.pinToggles').prop('checked', false)
    }
    else {
    $('.pinToggles').prop('checked', true)
    }
});
```

2) I have removed the `class` and `onclick` event handler in the below `checkbox` only.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="showHideAll">Show/Hide All<input type="checkbox" id="allCheck" name="pinSet" >
    <label for="allCheck" class="css-label"></label></div>
</div>
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/keTft/)

Comment: But with this if you check all the individual checkboxes and then check show/hide all it is displaying opposite of what it should.  It should be when select all is checked and if they uncheck one box select all is unchecked.

Comment: Same as before.  Try checking all three individual checkboxes so they are checked.  Then hit the select all.  It unchecks all of the individuals and it shouldn't.  The best example of showing what I want to happen is this fiddle  which is from the other question I saw http://jsfiddle.net/5XMW4/