# Check all checkboxes when select all is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to check all checkboxes when 'Select all' checkbox is checked. I've read various threads on SO, but not able to get the expected o/p.

Related Question:- [Select all checkboxes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228382/select-all-checkboxes-with-jquery)

Here's what I tried.

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="set_alarm">
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"><b>Select All</b></label><br>
    <label class="checkbox inline days"><input type="checkbox" id="Mon"><b>Mon</b></label>
    <label class="checkbox inline days"><input type="checkbox" id="Tue"><b>Tue</b></label>
    ......
    ......
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('.days').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery "select all" checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879608/jquery-select-all-checkbox)

Comment: Check out my answer, it does what you want and deselects the "check all" box when you select a different box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generalize your code more, there is a bunch of stuff in that other issue that isn't needed if you're just trying to select all checkboxes.

```
    $('#select_all').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
        $("input[type='checkbox']").not('#select_all').change( function() {
        $('#select_all').removeAttr('checked');
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/fK9C2/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

add a class on child checkboxes and do like this in one line:

### HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="set_alarm">
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"><b>Select All</b></label><br>
    <label class="checkbox inline days"><input type="checkbox" class="days" id="Mon"><b>Mon</b></label>
    <label class="checkbox inline days"><input type="checkbox"  class="days" id="Tue"><b>Tue</b></label>

</div>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {


        $('.days').prop("checked", this.checked);

});
```

$('.days').change(function(){

```
if($('input:checkbox:checked.days').length === $("input:checkbox.days").length)
{
    $('#select_all').prop("checked",true);
}
else
{
    $('#select_all').prop("checked",false);
}
```

})

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3NYT/1/)

Comment: Works good but , if I uncheck any one day, then 'select all' option should get unchecked as well.

Comment: you have to add little more in it then

Comment: I wrote this `$('.days').change(function() {
        if (!($(".days").is(':checked'))){
            $("#select_all").removeAttr('checked');
        }`

Comment: `$('.days').change(function() { $('#select_all').attr("checked", this.checked);

})`; Use this to uncheck select all.

Comment: As per your code, select all should get checked when all the days are checked. But it didnt worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this, if you don't want to modify your markup. **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/Y52tM/2/)**

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    $('.days input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", this.checked);
});
```

---

```
$('.days input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
```

OR

```
$('.days input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", this.checked);
```

---

Following is the code to unselect **Select All** if you uncheck on of the days.

```
$('.days input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        $('#select_all').attr("checked", this.checked);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

closest is for parent tree not next or previous siblings you can use nextAll:

```
var checkboxes = $(this).parent().nextAll('.days').find(':checkbox');
```

---

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).parent().nextAll('.days').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeProp('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example

```
$('#select_all').click(function() {
  var c = this.checked;
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked',c);
});
```

OR

```
$('#select_all').click(function() {
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Try below to select all checkboxes when `select_all` checked

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
   $('.days').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

and unselect `select_all` when one of the `days` checkbox unchecked.

```
$('.days').change(function() {
     if($(this).is(':checked')) 
     {     
       // check if all days checkbox checked then check select_all
       if($('.days').is(':checked').length == $('.days').length)
         $('#select_all').prop("checked", true); 
     }
     else
     {
        $('#select_all').prop("checked", false); 
     } 
 });
```